# On the use of the term "field of sets" in Maharam's papers

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory

I am reading some papers by D. Maharam, and feel a little bit confused about her use of the term "field of sets". Nowadays, I think the term is *standardly* used to mean a pair $(X, \mathscr{F})$ for which $X$ is a set and $\mathscr{F}$ a subfamily of the power set of $X$ that contains $X$ and is closed under finite unions, finite intersections, and absolute complements.

Yet, I got the impression that this may not have been the case some years ago. In particular, I'm drawing such a feeling from some of Maharam's papers, where measures are actually (real-valued, nonnegative, and) *finitely* additive, so that, in principle, there wouldn't be any reason, at least not a priori, for their domain to be closed under countable unions and intersections. For one of many examples, let me refer to the following:

> D. Maharam, *Finitely additive measures on the integers*, Sankhyā Ser. A **38** (1976), No. 1, 44-59.

The paper is available [on JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/25050025?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). In it, Maharam proves a number of results about measures (totally) defined on the power set of $\bf N^+$, with the frequent remark that this, however, is done only for the sake of simplicity and the results do actually extend to "arbitrary (finite, finitely additive) measures on an arbitrary field of subsets of an arbitrary set", just to put it in her own words from p. 49.

Nonetheless, I don't see how a theorem like the one she proves on the very same page can be established for an arbitrary (finite, finitely additive) measure on an arbitrary field of sets, provided that the term "field of sets" has to be intended in the sense most of us (?) use it today, and on the other hand, I couldn't find any definite evidence that "field of sets" in Maraham's work is really used in the sense of our "sigma-algebra". So I guess my question is: Do you see a solution to this puzzle?

**Added later.** The theorem under scrutiny in the above, which came back to my mind after reading [Eric Wofsey's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/225689/16537) to a related question on non-atomic, countably additive, non-negative measures $\mu: \Sigma \to \bf R$ (where $\Sigma$ is a sigma-algebra), reads:

> A measure $\mu: \mathcal P(\mathbf N^+) \to \bf R$ is full-valued if, and only if, for each $\varepsilon > 0$, $\mathbf N^+$ can be covered by a finite number of sets each of measure less than $\varepsilon$.

The proof is ultimately based on the construction of a *measurable* set as the union of *countably* many measurable sets defined by a straightforward induction, and "full-valued" is just another way to say that the measure $\mu$ has the weak, and hence the strong, Darboux property, viz. if $X \subseteq \mathbf N^+$ and $a \in [0, \mu(X)]$ then there exists a set $Y \subseteq X$ such that $\mu(Y) = a$.

Comment: I think you may be right.  Long ago the term "field of sets" meant what we now call "$\sigma$-algebra of sets".  However, I looked in some old books on my shelf and did not find examples of that.  Certainly by 1976 that would have been no longer the case.  But of course mathematicians educated using some old terminology may continue to use it even after it generally changes.

Comment: I thought the same, and tried to look for: D. Maharam, *On measure-preserving transformations*, Thesis (Ph.D.) - Bryn Mawr College, 1940, where it's likely we could get some clues. But unfortunately, the link to the thesis provided on MathScinet (search.proquest.com/docview/301790974) doesn't work, in the sense that the thesis can't be retrieved from it (AFAICS). Other clues could come from a paper of Banach and Tarsky: *Sur les décompositions dénombrables*, Fund. Math. **6** (1924), 244-277, that Maharam refers to on the 1st line of: (...)

Comment: (...) *On Measure in Abstract Sets*, TAMS **51** (1942),  No. 2, 413-433, if only it were not for the fact that there is no trace of it in the 6th volume of Fund. Math. (https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/fundamenta-mathematicae/all/6). Yet, this paper of Maharam is telling us something, as it is aimed at a general theory of measures "defined for some field of sets" that is, in fact, framed in the language and setting of (complemented, distributive) sigma-lattices.

Comment: Here there is another example: an article of Chow in the Annals of Statistics http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177700166, where he uses from the beginning the word "field" as what we currently mean as "sigma-algebra"..