How probability-rich is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a sequence of sets? (Sierpiński's theorem on non-atomic measures without using the AoC.)
$\newcommand\F{\mathcal F}\newcommand\si{\sigma}\newcommand\Om{\Omega}\newcommand\ep{\varepsilon}$Let  $p\in(0,1)$ and let $(\Om,\F,P)$ be a probability space. Let $(A_n)$ be a sequence in $\F$ such that $P(A_n)\to p$ as $n\to\infty$.
Without using the axiom of choice, can it then be shown that,

necessarily, for each real $\ep>0$ there is some set $B_\ep\in\F$ such that $P(B_\ep)\in[p,p+\ep)$?


One may note that, without loss of generality, the $\si$-algebra $\F$ is generated by the $A_n$'s.

Motivation: A positive answer to this question would provide a proof of Sierpiński's theorem on non-atomic measures without using the axiom of choice.
(On the other hand, it is not hard to deduce the highlighted statement from Sierpiński's theorem.)

Oftentimes with measure and probability, one seeks to eliminate the axiom of choice, but keep dependent choice (and hence also countable choice), since DC enables an adequate theory of measure. But is that what you would allow here? It seems likely one could answer positively with DC.

@JoelDavidHamkins : Thank you for your comment. To my eye, untrained in mathematical logic, DC looks like "sure, how can it be otherwise?". :-) On the other hand, I guess the highlighted statement cannot proved without DC -- what is your opinion/intuition (or more than that?) about this? Anyhow, I would accept a proof using only DC (hopefully I would be able to understand it).

I was imagining that one would find the desired set by choosing things successively in a countable sequence, so as to get close to $p$, as desired. Such an argument would be a proof from DC, but I don't yet have a proof. I'm not sure which way it will go.

At least concerning the linked result of Sierpiński, there is a DC-only proof at https://mathoverflow.net/a/225689/35357

@MichaelGreinecker : Thank you for your comment. Now the highlighted result should follow, using the diagonal choice argument, right? And for the diagonal choice argument, DC is enough, right?

I'm not sure how the argument works, but if you mean the kind of argument that constructs a convergent subsequence from a sequence of subsequences, that does work with DC.

@MichaelGreinecker : If I am not mistaken, we can deduce the closedness of the range of a probability measure $P$ from Sierpiński's theorem using the following steps. (i) Represent $P$ as $(1-t)P_a+tP_{na}$, where $t\in[0,1]$, $P_a$ is a purely atomic probability measure,  and $P_{na}$ is a non-atomic probability measure. (ii) The range of $P_{na}$ is $[0,1]$, by Sierpiński's theorem. (iii) The range of $P_a$ is closed, by the diagonal choice argument. So, by (i)--(iii), the range of $P$ is closed, and hence the highlighted result follows.

Previous comment continued: We know that DC is enough for Steps (ii) and (iii). If DC is enough for Step 1 (which I hope it is), then DC is enough for the highlighted result.

In that case, I simply don't understand what the diagonal choice argument is.

@MichaelGreinecker : Let $(C_i){i\in I}$ be a family of distinct (and hence wlog pairwise disjoint) atoms of the purely atomic probability measure $P_a$ such that $\bigcup{i\in I}C_i=\Omega$, so that $I$ is at most countable and hence wlog $I$ the set of all integers in the set $[1,m]$ for some $m\in{1,\dots,\infty}$. Suppose $P_a(A_n)\to p$. For each $n$ and some $c_{n,i}$'s in ${0,1}$, $P(A_n)=\sum_{1\le i<m}c_{n,i}P(C_i)$.

Previous comment continued: Using the diagonal choice argument, we get $c_{n_k,i}\to c_i$ as $k\to\infty$ for some strictly increasing sequence $(n_k)$ of natural numbers, some $c_i$'s in  ${0,1}$, and all $i$, whence $p=\lim_{k\to\infty}P(A_{n_k})=\sum_{1\le i<m}c_i P(C_i)=P(\bigcup_{i\in I,c_i=1}C_i)$, so that $p$ is in the range of $P_a$.

I see. That is basically the sequential compactness of ${0,1}^\mathbb{N}$, which does follow from DC.

@MichaelGreinecker : Here it was just shown how the closedness of the range of a purely atomic probability measure reduces to the sequential compactness.

@MichaelGreinecker : Do you think DC is enough for Step (i)?

Yes, you are really just picking one maximal probability atom of the other to get the purely atomic part.

@MichaelGreinecker : Great! Since I have no expertise in mathematical logic and you seem to have it, would you mind summarizing the previous discussion in a formal answer, perhaps supplying some details and/or references (which might also be of interest to other users)?

I'll try my modest abilities tomorrow.

Here is a proof that probability measures have closed range under DC, summarized from the discussion with Iosif Pinelis. I try to be as explicit as possible about any choice arguments used.
For any probability measure $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, there exists $A\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $P$ is purely atomic on $A$ and purely nonatomic on $A^C$; the decomposition is usually not unique. To construct $A$, let $A_1$ be an atom of maximal probability. Given $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are defined, let $A_{n+1}$ be an atom in $\Omega\setminus(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n)$ of maximal probability. This gives us by DC a sequence of atoms $\langle A_n\rangle$ such that there are no atoms in $\Omega\setminus A$ for $A=\bigcup_n A_n$. We can assume by the usual trick that all atoms in the sequence are disjoint.  We can now define two finite measures $P^{\text{a}}$ and $P^{\text{na}}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ such that $P^{\text{a}}(E)=P^{\text{a}}(E\cap A)$ and $P^{\text{na}}(E)=(E\cap A^C)$. Then $P^{\text{a}}$ and $P^{\text{na}}$ are purely atomic and nonatomic, respectively, and $P=P^{\text{a}}+P^{\text{na}}$.
We know from this answer by Eric Wofsey that under DC, the range of a finite nonatomic measure is a closed and bounded interval. To show that every probability measure has a closed range under DC, it suffices, therefore, to show that $P^{\text{a}}$ has a closed range. So we can assume for the remainder that $P=P^{\text{a}}$. Let $\alpha$ be in the closure of the range of $P$. For every $m$, there exists some $E_m\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $|P(E_m)-\alpha|<1/m$. DC implies the countable axiom of choice, so we can select a sequence $\langle E_m\rangle$ with this property. In particular, $\alpha=\lim_m P(E_m)$.
Since $P$ is purely atomic we can, for our original sequence of atoms $\langle A_n\rangle$ and each $E_n$ canonically specify a number $c_{nm}$ such that $c_{nm}=1$ if $P(A_n\cap E_m)=P(A_n)$ and $c_{nm}=0$ if $P(A_n\cap E_m)=0$. Write $c_m$ for the sequence $\langle c_{nm}\rangle$. Viewing $P$ is a function on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ given by $P(c_1,c_2,\ldots)=\sum c_n P(A_n)$, we see that $P$ is continuous in the product topology.
We construct a limit point in the product topology of $\langle c_m\rangle$ by a diagonal argument. Either, $(c_{11},c_{12}, c_{13},\rangle)$ is infinitely often $0$ or infinitely often $1$. In the first case, take the subsequence with the $0$s, otherwise, the one with the $1$s. Continue this way for every coordinate to get a sequence of subsequences. Picking the diagonal elements gives you the desired limit point $\langle c_n^*\rangle$. No choice was needed for this argument. By the continuity of $P$, we have $\sum_n c_n^* P(A_n)=\alpha$. Since the $A_n$ are disjoint, $$P\bigg(\bigcup_{n:c_n^*=1} A_n\bigg)=\alpha.$$

Thank you for taking your time to write this answer.

@IosifPinelis I think you deserve credit for it too; I learned a lot from our discussion.

Thank you for your comment. For me, it was mainly learning experience.
